# Working on discord.js, and my bot keeps spamming the same message

Tags: discord.js

I've been working on a bot in discord.js and have made a basic bot. Whenever I try to use the 'dadjoke' or 'dadpun' command, it just sends the placeholder messages over and over again. Any help?

The code is here:

```
} else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}joke`)) {
            var repl = rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
        message.channel.send(repl);
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}pun`)) {
        var repl2 = pun[Math.floor(Math.random()*pun.length)];
        message.channel.send(repl2);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What placeholder messages?

Comment: dadjoke1, dadjoke2, dadpun1 , dadpun2. Just basic placeholders

Comment: OK, but where are these defined? What's in `rand` and `pun`? Your code randomly selects from the contents of those arrays.

Comment: The 2 variables are var rand =["dadjoke 1", "dadjoke 2"];
var pun =["dadpun 1", "dadpun 2"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your `client.on("message", ...)` code.

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code right here: 

`if (message.author.bot) return;
    client.on("message", async (message) => {`

and all it outputs in the terminal is message is not defined. Any ideas?
Also, the comment doens't show it but it's above the client.on.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out i need to put it underneath, rather than above. thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem!
Sorry that i did not respond before.

Comment: I should of had more clarification anyways.